# Is there a way to unzip a file with various subfolders?

Tags: java, unzip, zip

Is there a way to unzip a ZIP file with various subfolders in Java without needing to install any additional plugin.

For example, I would like to unzip the file https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4.1-bin.zip with this code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class unzipfile {

    private static void unzip(String zipFilePath, String zipFileName, String destDir) {
        System.out.print("Extracting " + zipFileName + "...");
        File dir = new File(destDir);
        // create output directory if it doesn't exist
        if(!dir.exists()) dir.mkdirs();
        FileInputStream fis;
        //buffer for read and write data to file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(zipFilePath);
            try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(fis)) {
                ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
                while(ze != null){
                    String fileName = ze.getName();
                    File newFile = new File(destDir + File.separator + fileName);
                    //create directories for sub directories in zip
                    new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();
                    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile)) {
                        int len;
                        while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                        }
                    }
                    //close this ZipEntry
                    ze = zis.getNextEntry();
                }
            }
            fis.close();
            System.out.println(" Done!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(" Error while extracting " + zipFileName);
            Logger.getLogger(unzipfile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            unzip(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("No valid arguments specified. Usage:\n");
            System.out.println("\'java unzipfile [ZIP file path with file name] [file name only] [target directory]\'");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

}
```

I run:

```
java unzipfile path\to\file\gradle-6.4.1-bin.zip gradle-6.4.1-bin.zip .
```

But when I run the full application it gives me the message:

```
Extracting gradle-6.4.1-bin.zip... Error while extracting gradle-6.4.1-bin.zip
may. 27, 2020 5:44:37 P.áM. unzipfile unzip
SEVERE: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\gradle-6.4.1\README (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:291)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:234)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:184)
        at unzipfile.unzip(unzipfile.java:29)
        at unzipfile.main(unzipfile.java:50)
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Print at least the message from the `IOException`, preferably the whole stack trace. You're effectively throwing away useful debugging information by not doing that.

Comment: I don't do that because I want to integrate this program with another one that downloads the file, so the error log will be annoying.

Comment: *FYI:* 1) You don't need to call `zis.closeEntry()`, so you can remove those two lines of code. --- 2) You use try-with-resources, but then have `fis` standalone? Bad! --- 3) Use the newer NIO.2 API instead of the old File I/O API. Error messages are much better (assuming you actually show them).

Comment: Please fix the very bad indentations of your code. It's very difficult to read, without misreading it.

Comment: @Lumito: 1. even if you remove it later you can add it now to debug your problem 2. calling `System.exit()` inside of a library is *way more* annoying than log lines, because the caller can never work around that ... 3. How do you plan to report problems with unzipping to the caller if they happen? Your method should have clearly defined behaviour when things go wrong.

Comment: @Andreas Updated the code with comments and the full error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I've found this working code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

public class unzipfile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = args[0];
        File srcFile = new File(filename);
        // create a directory with the same name to which the contents will be extracted
        String zipPath = filename.substring(0, filename.length()-4);
        File temp = new File(zipPath);
        temp.mkdir();
        ZipFile zipFile = null;
        try { 
            zipFile = new ZipFile(srcFile);
            // get an enumeration of the ZIP file entries
            Enumeration e = zipFile.entries();
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
                File destinationPath = new File(zipPath, entry.getName());
                //create parent directories
                destinationPath.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                // if the entry is a file extract it
                if (!entry.isDirectory())                     
                System.out.println("Extracting file: " + destinationPath);

                try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(entry))) {
                    int b;
                    byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationPath);

                    try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024)) {
                        while ((b = bis.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                            bos.write(buffer, 0, b);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error opening zip file" + ioe);
        }
         finally {
             try {
                 if (zipFile!=null) {
                     zipFile.close();
                 }
             }
             catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.out.println("Error while closing zip file" + ioe);
             }
         } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Not useful without an explanation.